# iTunes Connect имя разработчика

Tags: ios

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос, на каком этапе добавления приложения iTunes Connect пишется имя разработчика, которое указывается в AppStore?

Comment: когда аккаунт создается, по моему

Comment: То есть где спрашивает фамилию и имя? А если я хочу имя одним словом написать? Просто там два обязательных поля

Comment: Если вы регистрируетесь как физ лицо, ваше имя будет использовано, как имя разработчика. А зачем вам одним словом?

Comment: Просто не хочу указывать реальное имя, а указать никнейм

Comment: А потом выложите вы платное приложение, а Эпл вам откажется деньги переводить, потому что имя не совпадает с банковскими реквизитами :)

Comment: Вот блин, тоесть можно только реальное имя и фамилию указывать?

Comment: Я думаю можно и ник указать, просто чтоб два слова было - "Leci the Great" :)

Comment: Ладно, я так поняла лучше не рисковать)) Спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы зарегистрировались как физ лицо, ваше имя использованное при регистрации будет использоваться как имя разработчика в appStore.